# Accessing elements in a 2d Array of Vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have a 2d Array of Vectors declared as

```
Vector<int> v1[10][11];
```

and I want to accessing the elements inside the array. Would I treat the 2d array of vectors as a 3d array and access elements like this:

```
v1[9][10][0];
```

to access the first element of the last member of the array?

Comment: Yes, that's how you would access it.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector allows the [] operator, but I'm pretty sure your [9][10][0] is going to be out of bounds - you don't have anything there.
Assuming that you're opting for an array something like

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

...

100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109]
```

then the last element is going to be v1[9][10], corresponding to 109 in the picture.

If you want each element to be an array, I think you'll need

```
std::vector<int[sizeofarray]> v1[10][11];
//or just vector<int[size]> v1[10][11]; if using namespace std;
```